# Image align attribute in HTML 5

Tags: css, html

As align attribute has been deprecated. What is replacement of `<img align="middle">` in HTML 5?

Comment: design should not be in html, but rather css.

Comment: HTML5 has no deprecation concept (or at least no such term). The `align` attribute is described in HTML5 and browsers are required to support it, but authors “must not” use it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - my eclipse tells ![Attribute (border) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MMYA3.jpg) see attached snap

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use CSS's [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) property, specifically `vertical-align: middle`

```
<img src="image.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/inijem/1)

See this page for more information on [Aligning inline images with the vertical-align property](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/vertical-align/)

Comment: LOL "design should not be in html, but rather css", yes this is much better =)

Comment: img tag shouldn't be self-closing in html5